# maven use multiple profiles with iterator-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I have one pom.xml file contains multiple `<profile>`, when I use `mvn clean install -P dev,stage`, it only generate the **filter-stage** filter file under `${basedir}/target/filters/`, can someone tell me why it did not generate **filter-dev** filter file under the folder?

The code is shows like this:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>             
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>iterator</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>                                 
                                    <items>
                                        <item>abc</item>
                                        <item>access</item>                                     
                                    </items>

                                    <pluginExecutors>
                                        <pluginExecutor>
                                            <plugin>
                                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <version>2.7</version>
                                            </plugin>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                                                <filters>
                                                    <filter>src/main/resources/filters/filter-fi-environment/dev/filter-dev-@item@-wf.properties</filter>
                                                </filters>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </pluginExecutor>
                                        <pluginExecutor>
                                            <plugin>
                                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <version>1.7</version>
                                            </plugin>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <target name="rename_file">
                                                    <move
                                                            file="${basedir}/target/filters/filter-template-wf.properties"
                                                            tofile="${basedir}/target/filters/filter-dev-${item}-wf.properties" />
                                                </target>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </pluginExecutor>
                                    </pluginExecutors>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/package.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <finalName>batch-workflow</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>stage</id>
            <build>             
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>iterator</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>                                 
                                    <items>
                                        <item>abc</item>
                                        <item>access</item>                                     
                                    </items>

                                    <pluginExecutors>
                                        <pluginExecutor>
                                            <plugin>
                                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <version>2.7</version>
                                            </plugin>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                                                <filters>
                                                    <filter>src/main/resources/filters/filter-fi-environment/stage/filter-stage-@item@-wf.properties</filter>
                                                </filters>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </pluginExecutor>
                                        <pluginExecutor>
                                            <plugin>
                                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <version>1.7</version>
                                            </plugin>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <target name="rename_file">
                                                    <move
                                                            file="${basedir}/target/filters/filter-template-wf.properties"
                                                            tofile="${basedir}/target/filters/filter-stage-${item}-wf.properties" />
                                                </target>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </pluginExecutor>
                                    </pluginExecutors>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/package.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <finalName>batch-workflow</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Is the result a jar or a war file? What kind of project is this? Simple jar, or JEE or Spring/Spring Boot ?

Comment: Hi, it's a zip file. This is only for a simple project.

Comment: based on my pom file, every profile has a build tag, I think that's why even I give multiple profiles when do the maven build, it only run one profile. Is anyone has the idea if I want to run multiple build in different profile?

Comment: First question is the zip file really necessary or could it be a jar file as well? If so you could make it simpler by using: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin ? Can you make a full working example for example on GitHub so I could take a look?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. the multienv plugin is really good, unfortunately it cannot satisfy my requirement. By some reason, I cannot expose the code on Github. I have one question on iterator-maven-plugin, is it possible if I can have dynamic <items> inside the plugin?

Comment: Two things. If it does not fit your requirements please open an issue. Furthermore Can you give a full example what you mean ? Best would be an example project on Github...

Comment: my requirement is: different environment will have different <item>, and when we do the maven build, we can give parameters to decide which environment we will have, it can be one or multiple environments. My current solution is: inside iterator-maven-plugin, I will have 4 executions, each execution will have different <item>, but the environment is not dynamic. Could you please give some idea?

Comment: also this pom file will only generate one jar/war/zip file